# Create a column according to the levels of a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column (species) presenting 153 levels of a factor

```
> out80[1:10,1:3]
    Species Plots100 Plots80
1       02      901    2091
2       03      921    2094
3       04       29      60
4       05     1255    2145
5       06      563     850
6       07       38      53
7      08S      102     144
8       09      897    1734
9       10      503    1084
10      11      134     334
```

What I would like to do is look for this level of the factor in another column (code)of another data frame(species.tab2) and simply create another column in out80 with the name associated with this level from the column French name

```
> head(species.tab2[,1:3])
    var code     French_name
1 ESPAR    2   CHENE PEDONCULE
2 ESPAR    3   CHENE SESSILE
3 ESPAR    3   CHENE SESSILE
4 ESPAR    3   CHENE SESSILE
5 ESPAR    4   CHENE ROUGE
6 ESPAR    5   CHENE PUBESCENT
```

I have tried doing it with ifelse or with a loop but I can't get it to work.

So the result would be something like this:

```
    Species Plots100 Plots80  Name
1       02      901    2091  CHENE PEDONCULE
2       03      921    2094  CHENE SESSILE
```

etc...

EDIT: Here are the levels:

```
> out80$Species
[1] 02   03   04   05   06   07   08S  09   10   11   12P  12V  13B  13C  13G  14   15P  15S  16  
[20] 17C  17F  17O  18C  18D  18M  19   20G  20P  20X  21C  21M  21O  22C  22G  22M  22S  23A  23AB
[39] 23AF 23AM 23C  23F  23PA 23PC 23PD 23PF 23PM 23SO 23SS 24   25B  25C  25FD 25FR 25M   25R  25V 
[58] 26E  26OC 27C  27N  28   29AF 29AI 29CM 29EN 29LI 29MA 29MI 31   32   33B  33G  33N  34   36  
[77] 37   38AL 38AU 39   40   41   42   49AA 49AE 49AM 49BO 49BS 49C  49CA 49CS 49EA 49EV 49FL 49IA
[96] 49LN 49MB 49PC 49PL 49PM 49PS 49PT 49RA 49RC 49RP 49RT 49SN 49TF 49TG 51   52   53CA 53CO 53S 
[115] 54   55   56   57A  57B  58   59   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68CC 68CE 68CJ 68CL 68CM
[134] 68EO 68PC 68PM 68SC 68SV 68TG 68TH 69   69JC 69JO 70SB 70SC 70SE 71   72V  73   74H  74J  76  
[153] 77  

> species.tab2$code
[1] 2    3    3    3    4    5    5    5    6    6    6    7    08S  9    10   10   11   12P  12V 
[20] 12V  13B  13C  13G  14   14   14   15P  15S  15S  16   17C  17F  17O  17O  18C  18C  18D  18D 
[39] 18M  19   19   20G  20P  20X  21C  21M  21O  22C  22G  22G  22M  22S  23A  23A  23AB 23AF 23AM
[58] 23C  23F  23PA 23PA 23PC 23PD 23PF 23PM 23SO 24   25B  25C  25D  25E3 25FR 25M  25R  25V  26E 
[77] 26E  26OC 27C  27N  28   29AI 29CM 29EN 29MA 29MI 29LI 31   32   33B  33G  33N  34   36   37  
[96] 38AU 38AL 39   40   41   42   49AA 49AE 49AM 49BO 49BO 49BS 49C  49CA 49CS 49EA 49EV 49FL 49IA
[115] 49LN 49MB 49PC 49PL 49PM 49PS 49PT 49RA 49RC 49RP 49RT 49SN 49TF 49TG 51   52   53CA 53CO 53S 
[134] 54   55   56   57A  57B  58   59   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68CC 68CJ 68CL 68CM 68EO
[153] 68PC 68PM 68SC 68SV 68TG 68TH 69   69JC 69JO 70SB 70SC 70SE 71   72V  73   74H  74J  76   77
```

There are some repetition in code just due to the fact that for a same code, there are 2 or 3 different French names existing. For these I just want one of the name, doesn't matter which one it is.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess that 08S (species) == 8(code)?

Comment: No the levels are exactly the same. 08S species== 08S code. The thing is there are a lot more levels in species.tab2$code than in out80$species and I only want the French name of the levels I have.

Comment: @Tom. what is the maximum character length of `code` and `Species`?

Comment: @Tom, you've to tell us how `code` and `Species` are similar for us to give you an answer. From this data what you've provided it is **not** clear.

Comment: @Tom for future, use `dput(out80$Species)` and paste the output here.

Comment: Ok thank you for the editing. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using merge , after creating a new column `code` in out80

```
out80$code <- gsub('^0|S$','',out80$Species)
merge(out80,species.tab2)
code Species Plots100 Plots80   var     French_name
1    2      02      901    2091 ESPAR CHENE PEDONCULE
2    3      03      921    2094 ESPAR   CHENE SESSILE
3    3      03      921    2094 ESPAR   CHENE SESSILE
4    3      03      921    2094 ESPAR   CHENE SESSILE
5    4      04       29      60 ESPAR     CHENE ROUGE
6    5      05     1255    2145 ESPAR CHENE PUBESCENT
```

**EDIT**

Code and Species doesn't match for levels 01,02,...., so I create a new column to match them.

```
gsub('^0([0-9])$','\\1',out80$Species)
```

Comment: Thank you agstudy but I don't want to change the levels in the variable species. The "08s" has to stay the same. For some other number I have for instance "21c","21m" etc.. that are different levels of the variable and then will have different French names.

Comment: @Tom I created new column code so , the levels doesn't change.My question is the code 08S corresponds to which code in the table species.tab2? I assume already that 02 corresponds to 2...

Comment: Ok thank you. It is working. Thanks a lot for your help both agstudy and @Arun

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(out80)
# positive look ahead 
# match 0's at beginning followed by numbers 
# if found, replace all beginning 0's with ""
dt1[, key := sub("^[0]+(?=[0-9]+$)", "", Species, perl=T)]
setkey(dt1, "key")

dt2 <- data.table(species.tab2)
dt2[, code := as.character(code)]
dt2[, key := sub("^[0]+(?=[0-9]+$)", "", code, perl=T)]
setkey(dt2, "key")

merge(dt1, dt2)

#    key Species Plots100 Plots80   var code     French_name
# 1:   2      02      901    2091 ESPAR    2 CHENE_PEDONCULE
# 2:   3      03      921    2094 ESPAR    3   CHENE_SESSILE
# 3:   3      03      921    2094 ESPAR    3   CHENE_SESSILE
# 4:   3      03      921    2094 ESPAR    3   CHENE_SESSILE
# 5:   4      04       29      60 ESPAR    4     CHENE_ROUGE
# 6:   5      05     1255    2145 ESPAR    5 CHENE_PUBESCENT
```